# Sorting a field where the date difference is calculated at front end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, sorting, pagination

I have a pagination service which brings 20 records at a time and has two date fields for each record. In the UI I have to display the difference between these two dates in a column called **Number of days**. Now, I have to implement sorting on this field based on the number of days which is being calculated in my angular app by taking the difference between the two date fields returned from the API call. Is there a way to achieve this without having the number of days being calculated at the server side and sent to the angular app?
 Update:
The Api's have the support for sorting already which is like if you want the results to be sorted by a particular column we make a call like `/api/list?sortBy=columnName:asc`

Comment: You can send the sorting option(ascending/descending) to the server side API, fetch the records, create "number of days" field and then call the sorting API and then finally send the result to the client. This will save you one additional round of communication between client and server....

Answer (score 0):

Use a datatable that provides a sorting feature

https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/zeroConfig

Answer (score 0):

There are one filter available in angular , you can utilize it when your data will goes to display in view like this :

Here i am giving you just demo example as you haven't post your code here, so please consider it like that, you need to take guideline form it.

```
{{ [{
'name': 'Ari',
'status': 'awake'
}, {
'name': 'Q',
'status': 'sleeping'
}, {
'name': 'Nate',
'status': 'awake'
}] | orderBy: 'name' }}

<!--
[
{"name":"Ari","status":"awake"},
{"name":"Nate","status":"awake"},
{"name":"Q","status":"sleeping"}
]
-->
```